# When using TensorFLow / Keras, what is the most efficient way to get some metadata inside a custom cost function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

In my dataset, I have a binary Target column, some Features columns, and a Date column. I want to write a custom cost function that would first compute a cost-by-date quantity, then add all the costs up. But to do this, I would need to know inside the cost function the corresponding date for each data point in `y_pred` and `y_true`.

What would be the best way to do this to maximize performance? I have a couple of ideas:

- Make the target variable a tuple `(target, date)`, have a custom first layer that extracts the first entry of the tuple, and have the cost function extract the second entry of the tuple `y_true`
- Make the target column variable an index, and have the custom first layer as well as the custom cost function pull the relevant values from a global variable based on index

What is the most efficient way to get this information inside the custom cost function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a way you could do that. Im not quite sure how performant that would be but one way would be to use a CustomLoss of the following form

```py
def myLossWithDate(date_col):
    def customBinaryCrossEntropy(y_true, y_pred):
        print(list(zip(date_col, y_true.numpy())))
        # do smth here
        # return custom_loss or
        return tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true,y_pred)
    return customBinaryCrossEntropy
```

You can then use this loss in your model like so:

```py
mod = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
])
mod.compile(optimizer="sgd", loss=myLossWithDate(date_col=X[:,1]), run_eagerly=True)
mod.fit(X, Y, epochs=1, verbose=False)
```

The main thing here is to use

```py
run_eagerly=True
```

Otherwise you would get Iterator Tensors (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_graphs).
Depending on the data the output, due to the print(list(zip(...))) thingy looks like so

```py
[(1, array([0])), (2, array([1])), (3, array([1]))]
```

where I used

```py
Y = np.random.binomial(1, 0.5, 3).reshape(-1,1)
X = np.column_stack((np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([1,2,3]))) # data, date as int
```

as data.

Obviously this is just a dummy but maybe it will help you.

EDIT: Using minibatches

The function changes as follows

```py
def myLossWithDate():
    def customBinaryCrossEntropy(y_true, y_pred):
        y_true_ = y_true[:,0]
        batch_size = y_true.shape[0]
        y_true_ = tf.reshape(y_true_, shape=(batch_size, 1))
        date_col = y_true[:,1]
        # do smth here
        # return custom_loss or
        return tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true_,y_pred)
    return customBinaryCrossEntropy
```

and pass

```py
Y = np.column_stack((Y, date_col))
```

Since in backprop you usually do not use Y except for calculating the loss which you will do manually.

The model becomes

```py
batches = 2
batch_size = int(X.shape[0] / batches)

mod = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")
])
mod.compile(optimizer="sgd", loss=myLossWithDate(), run_eagerly=True)
mod.fit(X, Y, epochs=1, verbose=False, batch_size=batch_size)
```

Comment: Thanks! Would this work properly with mini-batches? Doesn't this closure have access to the the date column for the entire dataset, while y_true and y_pred will be only a subset of that?

Comment: Ah yes, good point. I append the answer in the comment above

Comment: Thanks again! And I would also need a custom first layer to ignore the metadata i.e. `Y[:,1]`, correct?

Comment: No you dont need one since in backprop you only use Y when calculating the loss. But Since you calculate the loss on your own you can just exclude Y[:,1]

Comment: Ahhhh good point, I was thinking of `X`, thanks! :)  And why do I still need to have `myLossWithDate` return `customBinaryCrossEntropy` if it is not a closure anymore? Does it have to do with running eagerly? Or I can just define `customBinaryCrossEntropy` in the global scope?